# Update DynamoDB item with optional operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is the following operation implementable in DynamoDB:
On providing the key,

- SET `status` as "active".
- **If** the attribute `additional_info` *starts_with* "xyz"

  - Then REMOVE `additional_info`
  - **Else** do nothing to `additional_info`

Basically, an update where we override value of `status` regardless of `additional_info`. And optionally unset `additional_info` as an attribute if a condition is satisfied?

Comment: Might have to be 2 item updates, perhaps in a transaction. The latter is conditional and uses begins_with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done in one call. It also can't be done in a single transaction wrapping the two calls into one, because a transaction can't repeatedly reference the same item.

If you can just make two calls, that's the way to go. If you need it to be somewhat transactional, you'll need to control things in your app. The details depend on your requirements.